# Designspark Positive/Negative Setting for Gerber grayed out

Tags: pcb, gerber

i want to create gerber files for a pcb. One gerber file per layer more specifically. I have made gerber file on designspark many times before, but now the Positive/Negative option in output manufacturing plots>Settings  is grayed out. ( see picture, on the right side, Design 2).

[image]

On my 'malfunctioned Design 2', This option only gets activated when i create/Add plots by selecting the 'windows' option, while i need the "gerber/Photo plot option.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be well documented, but I think this option is only available for layers that are designated as "power plane" during the initial setup or in "Design Technology"/Layers tab.

Comment: Yes you are right. They solved my problem here: https://designspark.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/7087

I sont know if you can see it.